# post comment dont show the pdf file wordpress

Tags: posts, comments, pdf

we use Wordpress6.4.1 and I would like to add a PDF document in Post Comment. I do it but I can't open the document. do you have a solution?

Comment: Welcome! We'll need more details before we can answer the question. Please include any related custom code you may have implemented this functionality with, or a screenshot of what you're referring to, along with the expected result.